# How to attach a table to another table horizontally?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How to attach a table to another table horizontally?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}




\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline 
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]
The above two tables have to be combined such that the first table and the second table are horizontally attached.

That is,

[image]

### MWE ( which I tried).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can attach them horizontally, but not *merge* them. They may seem merged if they have the same number of rows. However, if they have differing row numbers, then you'll have to manually edit the lesser-row table to insert blank rows to match.

Answer (score 4):

`tabular` are positioned exactly the same way as letters.

```
XY
```

are set adjacent

```
X
Y
```

are set side by side with one word space between

```
X

Y
```

are set as two paragraphs one above the other.

You might also want to use `\begin{tabular}[t]` in both cases, so they align on the top row, rather then vertical centre.

So....

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c}
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
some thing & some thing & some thing \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline     One &One &One &One  \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @AlanMunn no, just need to remove one `|` the space at the space at the outer edge is half the inter-column space so two tabular fit together

Comment: @AlanMunn If the OP had provided one, i would have used it:-)

Comment: kindly provide the codes using my codes..@DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I have given an mwe.. kindly give me an edit in that.

Comment: @David see update